# Dynamically resizing UITableViewCell again

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Well, I've been searching a lot to solve my problem, however, I haven't found anything useful.

I have my custom cells, which can(or can't) contain images, text, titles, etc in free order, so I need to set the row's height depending on its content.
Like these two: http://db.tt/AVBKYuEY
http://db.tt/HbnXMMFn

The only way I can make them is by storyboard.

So, I call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndex:`
and set there the whole contents
and then I want to set the height of the row, BUT I can't do it, because the row's height is set in `tableView:height...`:, which is called BEFORE `tableView:cellForRowAtIndex:`

Btw, I also have constraints in my storyboard, so, it would be great if I could use them to count the cell height.

And also it perfectly changes width when I rotate iPhone, what is strange in fact that I can't change height

How to solve my problem?

Comment: What you can do is have a data structure like an array or what ever which holds the height in advance and then use it in heightForRowAtIndexPath to return the correct value. In that process, you can even have your cell content pre-done and may be render the cells even faster. You can have all of this logic in viewWillAppear or some other place.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height in tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:. You have access in that method to the index path and therefore the index of the array supplying the data to the cell. So, you need to look at that data, and do any calculations that are needed to determine the cell height, and return that value.

After Edit: Here's an example of calculating height for a multi-line label. I create a temporary label, fill it with the text that this row will contain, and then use sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:LineBreakMode: to do the calculation:

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.numberOfLines = 0; // allows label to have as many lines as needed
    label.text = _objects[indexPath.row][@"detail2"]; // this is the data I'm passing in the detail label
    CGSize labelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, 300000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    CGFloat h = labelSize.height;
    return h + 50; //50 is base height for my cell with only one line of text, determined empirically
}
```

Comment: As I understood, I can access my cell with tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, right? And it returns UITableViewCell. But I need it to return my custom cell.

Comment: @PhilippConstantinopolski, You don't want to access the cell in the heightForRowAtIndexPath method (if that's what you're talking about), you want to access the data to do height calculations based on the content. You might need to add some value (for a base height) based on how big you made your custom cell, but that value should be fixed by the height of the cell you made in IB.

Comment: http://db.tt/8ZpJkFDd Tried to explain what I need. I can set height only at step one? Can I also set contents there? Or can I access my custom cell constraint values there?

Comment: Step 1 shouldn't be used, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that. As I said in my answer, you do the calculations in the heightForRowAtIndexPath based on the values you get from your  data, NOT from your cell -- do not access your cell here. If you have text in a text view or multi line label, you calculate the height based on that text. If you have an image, calculate the height based on the height of the image, etc. I've added an example in my answer to calculate height of a multi line label.

Comment: Do you know other ways of doing that? It would be great if there were no calculations at all. I know (void)sizeToFit. What does it actually do?

Comment: I don't know how to make sizeToFit be constrained to the width of your label. In the method I used, you give it a maximum size ({300,30000} in my example), so I don't let the label be any wider than my cell (portrait for iPhone in this case).